# Assign Group Permission to Distribution Group SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, distribution-lists

I have a Distribution Group in AD and i want to assign permission to same in SharePoint 2013 on-premise. But i am not able to get that group in people picker. However, i am able to fetch the Security Group from AD to SharePoint.

Please advice.
UPDATE: I just came across an [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10550.sharepoint-2010-choosing-between-ad-groups-or-sharepoint-groups.aspx) which states Distribution Group cannot be assigned permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@404, yes that's right, if you want to assign permissions to AD groups, they have to be security groups not distriubution groups.